# Mass Find and Replace between an XML file and a PL file

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, xml

I'm trying to edit a playlist file which references Arcade ROMS, which are named in MAME standard of six letters, but I need the reference to be replaced to the actual name in a database so I can pull data from there, such as boxarts and screenshots.

I have an XML file that contains the MAME name and then the actual name, and then I have my PL file that references the actual file and how should RetroArch open it.

XML has the following data

```
<game>
    <mamename>alpham2</mamename>
    <realname>Alpha Mission II / ASO II - Last Guardian (NGM-007)(NGH-007)</realname>
</game>
```

The Playlist file is filled with the following tags

```
{
      "path": "N:\\Juegos\\emuladores\\NeoGeo\\alpham2.zip",
      "label": "alpham2",
      "core_path": "C:\\Users\\roshr\\Documents\\RetroArch\\cores\\fbneo_libretro.dll",
      "core_name": "FinalBurn Neo",
      "crc32": "00000000|crc",
      "db_name": "FBNeo - Arcade Games.lpl"
    },
```

I need to pull the data at the end of the `"path"` string and search for it in the `<mamename>stuff</mamename>` tag, if it's present then replace the string in `"label"` with the one in `<realname>Stuff Named (Country)</realname>` and then loop it until the end of the PL file, but I don't even know where to start cross-referencing these files.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: Please, [don't cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58234414/372239)